# How to fix this JSON Error with Joomla 3.7, CiviCRM 4.7.19, PHP 7.1?

Tags: joomla

To evaluate CiviCRM, I've installed CiviCRM 4.6.26/Joomla 3.6.5, subsequently upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.19/Joomla 3.7 site that is running PHP 7.1.

The backend 4.7.19/3.7 install appears to work fine, but when I define a CiviCRM Dashboard or anything else as a front-end menu option, I get

```
RuntimeException: Error decoding JSON data: 
Syntax error in /home/hillcresttm/public_html/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Format/Json.php:72 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/hillcresttm/public_html/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php(366): 
  Joomla\Registry\Format\Json->stringToObject('{"menu_image":"...', Array) 
#1 /home/hillcresttm/public_html/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php(72): 
  Joomla\Registry\Registry->loadString('{"menu_image":"...') 
#.............
```

Various Joomla support forums indicate that message is likely a problem with JSON data that is not valid. In Joomla versions prior to 3.6.3 (October, 2016) this failed silently, but since 3.6.3, it generates an error.

I've cleared/disabled my Joomla caching with no change in the error. I found a CiviCRM item on cache, but the directory structure did not match my installation.

Any suggestions for how to proceed?

Bruce

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2017, I'd say PHP 7.1 / CiviCRM combination is probably not ready for production use - I tried it the other day and ran into some errors. If you need to run CiviCRM in production, I'd switch down to PHP 7.0.x or 5.6.x.

You might be able to get it to behave with some other configuration changes or by being more actively engaged in CiviCRM development, but for a production site I'd recommend shifting down to 7.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try emptying the Civi cache at ~/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_us? Then refresh the browser.

Also, what is your PHP memory limit set at? Try 128mb.

I've the same install without those issues. What OS?

Answer (score -1):

You must disable JB Library plugin

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't appear to answer the question.  Could you please provide more details?